# How to create one "unit" test per query to display the result in the Test Explorer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

Right now my job is to test all the queries stored in a database, and display the result in the *Test Explorer*, I've managed to test every query (I just run it, check for errors and store a custom error message for each error in a text file so it work for now but the output is not as I want it to be).

**DISCLAMER**
I guess unit testing may not be the smartest way to test the queries but that is the way i was asked to do it so I'm giving it a try.

The thing is that I test all queries within one `[TestMethod]` and the result look like this : (only one test method in the *Test Explorer*)

[image: Test explorer result]

But I would want to know if it is possible to have multiple `[TestMethod]`, so we can see which methods work and which don't within the *Test Explorer*.

[image: Test explorer result 2]

My researches led me to this code :

```
[TestMethod]
[DataSource("System.Data.SqlClient",
            @"Data Source=****;Initial Catalog=****;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=****;Pooling=False",
            "Query",
            DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]    // My DataSource works
public void MyTestMethod()
{
        var q = new QueryDto
        {
            // Create my query with the Id, Name, Query, Parameters...
        };

        ExecTest(q);
}

public void ExecTest(QueryDto query)
{
       // my testing here
}
```

I've tried adding `[TestMethod]` to the `ExecTest()` method but it did not helped very much with what I'm trying to achieve.

So please tell me if what I'm looking for is **possible**, and if it is, how to do it.

Feel free to ask questions \ edit I'll stay tuned so you don't have to wait if you try to help me.

### EDIT

I'm posting another question because this one have some mistakes
Thanks for the help btw ^^.

Comment: The query is unclear and probably not about SQL Server. You can have as many tests in a class as you want. Just add the proper attribute to each method. `ExecTest` is a *helper* method you created, not a test itself

Comment: On the other hand, unit testing is best done in the same language as the source. [tSQLt](https://tsqlt.org/) is a unit testing framework for SQL Server that's used by Redgate in its own tools

Comment: Sorry Panagiotis, i forgot to mention that i would want the methods created programmatically because there is a hundred of them. Doing something like a "ForEach" that would create `TestMethod`s

Comment: I'm gonna take a look to tSQLt thanks !
But i'm still looking for a way to get the results in the _Test Explorer_

Comment: Is this really a Unit Test? Automated, maybe, but Unit?

Comment: @Aron That's why i was asking if that was possible, i just want a way to get it to the _Test Explorer_ Unit or not ^^, I'm not well trained on Tests in visual studio so i went for the only thing i knew (Unit Test)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now i'll stick to the answer i got here [create test programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56340288/create-test-programmatically)

my code :

```
[TestMethod]
[DataSource("System.Data.SqlClient",
            @"Data Source=****;Initial Catalog=****;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=****;Pooling=False",
            "Query",
            DataAccessMethod.Sequential)] 
public void MyTestMethod()
{
           // my testing here using TestContext.DataRow["columnName"] to get the Name, id, Parameters...
}
```

This displays the tests like shown :

[image]

In the top part of the *Test Explorer* it is still displayed as a single test but at least all the lines are detailled in the lower part and i can display a custom message to give some info about which query failed so it's fine.