# Create test programmatically

Tags: c#, testing

Quick question : 
 Can I programmatically create tests in visual studio and have them displayed into the *Test Explorer*  ? is it doable ?

I'm using the logic of [Data driven tests](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/visualstudio/test/how-to-create-a-data-driven-unit-test?view=vs-2015) so i can actually do all my tests but they are displayed in only one test in the *Test Explorer* because this method uses only one `[TestMethod]`

so is there a way to do something in the logic of :

```
foreach(item in list)
{
     // Create a "[TestMethod]" that will be displayed in the Test Explorer
}
```

The *"foreach"* is already done with the [Data driven tests](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/visualstudio/test/how-to-create-a-data-driven-unit-test?view=vs-2015) but maybe there is another way that allow to cycle through my data and **create a Test for each entry** ?
Thanks :)

Comment: Just that im not misunderstanding you, you want to create code programmatically? Also a [mcve] would be nice

Comment: Hey MindSwipe ! the thing is that i have no idea how to code this so i don't think i can add some useful code (i'm gonna try tho) ^^
And yeah create code programmatically could be one solution !

Comment: There's an msdn article about compiling code programmatically [here](https://support.microsoft.com/de-de/help/304655/how-to-programmatically-compile-code-using-c-compiler). Ypu might also want to look at the [Roslyn scripting api](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Scripting-API-Samples). [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/dynamic-source-code-generation-and-compilation) article about dynamic code generation and compilation could also help

Comment: Thanks a lot ! i'll look into it ! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using MSTEST for testing, you will have to write a custom datasource.
Then your test will be displayed as multiple test in test explorer.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/how-to-create-a-data-driven-unit-test?view=vs-2019

In case of NUnit you can use ***TestCase*** attribute this behavior

http://nunit.org/docs/2.5/testCase.html

In case of XUnit you can use Theory and ***InlineData*** for achieving this behavior

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-with-dotnet-test#adding-more-features

Comment: Thanks ! I think this is the closest we can get without creating code programmatically